# disble cdkDragLockAxis while dragging

Tags: angular, angular-material

i want to disable cdkDragLockAxis while dragging element at specific position

```
<div cdkDrag cdkDragLockAxis="y" #cdkDiv (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event, cdkDiv)" ></div>
```

in ts

```
dragMoved(ev,div) {
  if(ev.distance.y < -100) {
    //disable cdkDragLockAxis
  }
}
```